# My facebook like button is not showing up

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I looked at previous asked questions about the facebook like button and didnt see anything that was wrong with my code. Here is what I have:

```
<body>

 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}
 (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


</body>
```

Comment: Is your console logging any errors? Also have you placed the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page ?

Comment: no it has not shown any errors. I took the code straight from the facebook website

Comment: Have you added this `div` also `<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After adding the code for initializing the Facebook's Javascript SDK you also have to add the code to display the Like button at the required place. The generic code for it is

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true">
</div>
```

If you want you can further customize it by checking documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

Comment: Neither in mine. I realized the iframe width and height are set to 0px. If I manually change that after the page is rendered, the button shows up. I wonder why data-width is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, once I published the page, the like buttons showed up

**facebook page : settings : Page Visibility : Page published**

(the page was "unpublished" by default even after I did publish it for the first time)

Answer (score 1):

I know topic is old but still coming up in searches.
Here's the initialization code I used:

```
 (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

**Important**:

1. By default Facebook auto-configuration tool (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/follow-button) does not prepend "HTTPS" when exporting the js.src element.
2. If testing this on localhost host you will run into problems with the button visibility (c.f. v2.9) Either use a https tunnel service such as ngrok or deploy to valid **https** server.

Comment: As a further update, Facebook will now block **ngrok** localhost tunnel. Official response from Facebook bug report team is to use **localtunnel** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/localtunnel) is using Nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Adding version to the url `js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11";` helped in my case.