# Facebook follow button is not showing up during local development

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I have gone through following similar issues of people having trouble with their Facebook social plugins: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020641/facebook-button-not-showing-up), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207054/my-facebook-like-button-is-not-showing-up) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414223/follow-button-issue). None of this helped to solve the problem + posts are a bit outdated. I have also posted on the Facebook for developers site - no response for now.

Here is my simple HTML page: https://jsfiddle.net/jhmyzwbk/3/ 
This MWE shows two different options of my tryings to integrate Facebook like button both of them do not work for some reason.

Just for the sake of it, I have tried the same procedure with Twitter follow button integration and everything works like a charm.

One more notice, when I try to open html on my local machine in Chrome gives me the following error: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` `://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js`. But when I enter`http://` before `js.src = "://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";` error dissapears, but again no sign of Like icons anywhere.

**UPDATE:** @CBroe suggested to move development to local server, what apparently was one of the half way through the solution. Rechecking the received code from Facebook I come up with a following thing https://jsfiddle.net/jhmyzwbk/6/. Now, you won't see anything on jsfiddle but if you copy and run this code on your web server everything works. Double check that you're running your static HTML page on web server otherwise nothing works.

Comment: What does “local development” actually mean? You should use a local web server to test and develop, so that you can access your pages via HTTP.

Comment: @CBroe why would I need to install, let's say XAMPP, for writing simple HTML/CSS pages? If the script is written inside the HTML and all the links to the outside world `href` are written properly everything should work. Is not the HTTP requests are more connected to PHP?

Comment: Using a local webs erver during development, even if it is for mostly “static” pages, is always a good idea IMHO, because it enables you to test under _realistic_ conditions. And the protocol-relative URLs Facebook uses in their code to embed the SDK just don’t work if the page is _not_ called via HTTP(S). Of course you can try and modify the code accordingly – but who can say if testing without a web server doesn’t cause other problems? (F.e., the SDK checks what domain it is embedded on, to see if that matches your app settings. No web server == no host name == potential additional problem.)

Comment: Did the same thing with Apache server running on my local machine. Same result. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @CBroe added an update to my post. Now everything seems to work for some magical reason. Thanks for staying on this case! This was driving me nuts the whole day. Couldn't be such a simple function to be so hard to implement.